# Be careful your GUI work(click or drag to photo) in javaFX when using transparent PNG file

Tags: javafx

(English expression is very hard to me. Please correct my writing if anyone fine strange expression.)

Be careful, if you have a mind to use PNG file when make draggable or click action.

Sometimes **transparent PNG** will disturb dragging and click action.
So, if you want to use PNG on your dragging or click action work, use opaque PNG.

Last week, I tried to make a draggable imageview on tilepane.
It looks like photo tile puzzle.
I applied clicking and dragging action.
Then it sometimes worked and sometimes didn't workd.
I wondered why it is.
So I tried test over and over again.
Finally, I could fine a clue.
One transparent PNG has a opaque part and transparent part.
Thus, the task works when click opaque part and doesn't work when click transparent part. Lets see details below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both result is different. One thing point to **imageview**, and another thing point to hbox(parent of imageview).

1.When click opaque part of PNG

```
@FXML
private void tile1MouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
   System.out.println("result : " + event.getTarget()); 
}
```

result : ImageView@7afa16c0

2.When click transparent part of PNG

```
@FXML
private void tile1MouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
   System.out.println("result : " + event.getTarget()); 
}
```

result : HBox@3f30efe6

```
String[] imageName = {"slide1.png", "slide2.png", "slide3.png", "slide4.png", 
                        "slide5.png", "slide6.png", "slide7.png", "slide8.png"};
    Image img = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < imageName.length; i++) {
        try {
            img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream(imageName[i]));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("exception : " + e);
        }
        ImageView imageview = new ImageView(img);
        imageview.setFitWidth(20);
        imageview.setFitHeight(20);

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.getChildren().add(imageview);
        tile1.getChildren().add(hbox);
}
```